# How to make expansion tile in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am confusing with expansion tile in flutter. Actually i want to make a expansion tile, will be share here in image,

[image]

This is actual want to create, when  am trying make this one using expansion tile, its getting errors, have anyone know how its make expansion tile, or nay other methods, please add any reference or your ideas

Comment: please share your code, or maybe the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Create a List at the parent widget to save the state of the items whether expanding or not. Pass it to your item as a parameter

For example:

```
List<bool> isExpandingList; // length is equal to the data list's length

YourItem(isExpanding: isExpandingList[index])
```

Comment: i want to make a type of expansion tile, as i  image mentioned in my question , that one is i am stucking